# Eigen LLT Module Giving incorrect result?

Tags: c++, r, eigen, rcpp

First off, I assume the problem is with me and not with Eigen's LLT module. That said, here is the code (I will explain the problem briefly) but sourcing the code in Rstudio should recreate the bug.

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

template <typename T>
void fillUnitNormal(Eigen::PlainObjectBase<T>& Z){
  int m = Z.rows();
  int n = Z.cols();
  Rcpp::NumericVector r(m*n);
  r = Rcpp::rnorm(m*n, 0, 1); // using vectorization from Rcpp sugar
  std::copy(std::begin(r), std::end(r), Z.data());
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> 
// @param z is object derived from class MatrixBase to overwrite with sample
// @param m MAP estimate
// @param S the hessian of the NEGATIVE log-likelihood evaluated at m
// @param pars structure of type pars
// @return int 0 success, 1 failure
int cholesky_lap(Eigen::MatrixBase<T1>& z, Eigen::MatrixBase<T2>& m, 
                 Eigen::MatrixBase<T3>& S){
  int nc=z.cols();
  int nr=z.rows();
  Eigen::LLT<MatrixXd> hesssqrt;
  hesssqrt.compute(-S);
  if (hesssqrt.info() == Eigen::NumericalIssue){
    Rcpp::warning("Cholesky of Hessian failed with status status Eigen::NumericalIssue");
    return 1;
  }
  typename T1::PlainObject samp(nr, nc);
  fillUnitNormal(samp);
  z = hesssqrt.matrixL().solve(samp);
  z.template colwise() += m;
  return 0;
}

// @param z an object derived from class MatrixBase to overwrite with samples
// @param m MAP estimate (as a vector)
// @param S the hessian of the NEGATIVE log-likelihood evaluated at m 
//    block forms should be given as blocks row bound together, blocks 
//    must be square and of the same size!
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::MatrixXd LaplaceApproximation(int n_samples, Eigen::VectorXd m, 
                                          Eigen::MatrixXd S){
  int p=m.rows();
  MatrixXd z = MatrixXd::Zero(p, n_samples);
  int status = cholesky_lap(z, m, S);
  if (status==1) Rcpp::stop("decomposition failed");
  return z;
}

/*** R
library(testthat)

n_samples <- 1000000
m <- 1:3
S <- diag(1:3)
  S[1,2] <- S[2,1] <- -1
S <- -S # Pretending this is the negative precision matrix
        # e.g., hessian of negative log likelihood


z <- LaplaceApproximation(n_samples, m, S)
expect_equal(var(t(z)), solve(-S), tolerance=0.005)
expect_equal(rowMeans(z), m, tolerance=.01)

  */
```

Here is the (key) output:

```
> expect_equal(var(t(z)), solve(-S), tolerance=0.005)
Error: var(t(z)) not equal to solve(-S).
2/9 mismatches (average diff: 1)
[1] 0.998 - 2 == -1
[5] 2.003 - 1 ==  1
```

**In Words:**
I am trying to write a function to perform a Laplace approximation. This means essentially sampling from a multivariate normal with mean `m` and covariance `inverse(-S)` where `S` is the Hessian of the negative log-liklihood.

My code works perfectly for an eigen decomposition I coded but for some reason, it is failing with the Cholesky. (I have tried to just give a minimal reproducible example and for space am not showing the eigen decomposition).

The best thought I have now is that some aliasing issue is happening but I can't figure out where that would be...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a simple math error. Not a code error. Issue was that cholesky of matrix inverse has a transpose compared to just the inverse of the cholesky of the original matrix. Changing

```
  z = hesssqrt.matrixL().solve(samp);
```

to

```
  z = hesssqrt.matrixU().solve(samp);
```

Solved the problem.